# Using NUnit with generic discriminated unions

Tags: generics, f#, nunit, discriminated-union

I'm trying to use FsUnit (under the hood it uses NUnit) to test my F# code, but it's having trouble handling generic discriminated unions. I understand why it happens, but I'm trying to find a way to write tests without annotating my expected values. Any advice? Are there maybe frameworks better suited for this?

```
type OptionWithReason<'a> =
  | Some of 'a
  | None of string

let reason = "division by 0 is not yet supported"
let safeDivide x y = 
    if y = 0 then 
        None reason
    else
        Some(x/y)

let result = safeDivide 1 0

let expected = None reason
let expectedExplicit: int OptionWithReason = None reason

let test1 = result = expected //true
let test2 = result = expectedExplicit //true

NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(expectedExplicit,result) //pass
NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(expected,result) //fail :(
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A part of the problem in your code is that `Assert.AreEqual` takes two parameters as `obj` and so the compiler does not know that the types should be the same - if it knows this, then it would infer that `expected` is of type `int OptionWithReason` (to match with `result`).

An easy way to fix this is to define a helper function for `areEqual` that takes parameters of the same type:

```
let areEqual (first:'T) (second:'T) = 
  NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(first, second)
```

Now you can write your assertion as:

```
areEqual expected result
```

The compiler will infer that the types of `expected` and `result` are the same and it should work.

Comment: Nice, your solution is actually much simpler than what I found (switching to Unquote). I'm going to mark it as accepted, although I will stick with Unquote, as it's a cool library to use in my toy project :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I found it. `Unquote` seems to work. I used it with xUnit just because it was easier to setup with dotnet core libraries. I only needed to import the libraries and change asserts:

```
open Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Fact>]
let testDUComparison () = 
    test <@ expected = result @>

[<Fact>]
let testDUComparisonExplicit () = 
    test <@ expectedExplicit = result @>
```

This kind of dodges the issue, because we're using F#'s equality instead of passing it to a C# library as `OptionWithReason<object>`

Answer (score 1):

```
let expected = None reason
```

Here, compiler can't know the type of generic parameter `'a`, so if use use it in

```
NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(expected,result)
```

It would become equivalent to an instance of `OptionWithReason<object>` which would different from any instance of `OptionWithReason<int>`, as the case of `result`

As for test framework, you could try [Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto). But still, I think it would pose the same problem

Comment: Like I said : I understand why it happens, I'm looking for a better solution than annotating

Comment: Then I guess the answer is no, because without type annotating, it would be different type